# Netbeans OptionsPanelController buttons focus

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using a netbeans platform's `OptionsPanelController`,

from https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-options.html this tutorial.

My question is , 
by using this panel the `Ok button` is focused by default.

How can i make it not focused by default.

**Note :**

Since its a netbeans platform application, i opened `Tools->Options`
 from Netbeans IDE, in that dialog also Ok button was focused by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard-coded to behave that way in a private package and final class in the netbeans source code, hence it can be done, but requires either making modifications to the netbeans source code and changing your code to depend on your own version of netbeans, or using reflection or java bytecode injection to override the existing behavior.

The classes of interest that you will need to modify are:
org.netbeans.api.options.OptionsDisplyer and 
org.netbeans.api.options.OptionsDisplayerImpl

More specifically, the method OptionsDialogImpl.showOptionsDialog(...) creates a DialogDisplayer object that has the default selected value set to DialogDescriptor.OK_OPTION, which results in the OK button being selected whenever the Tools->Options window is opened.

Your only work-arounds/hacks are:
Option 1) Build your own version of netbeans changing the hard-coded behavior to be what you need. You will need to clone and build from source netbeans code; See instructions available at: http://wiki.netbeans.org/WorkingWithNetBeansSources#Try_NetBeans_buildSimply

Once you checkout/clone the source you will want to edit around line 204 in OptionsDisplayerImpl.java replacing input argument DialogDescriptor.OK_OPTION, with your preferred button, say DialogDescriptor.CANCEL_OPTION. The line you need to edit is given below.

```
descriptor = new DialogDescriptor(optionsPanel,title,modal,options,DialogDescriptor.OK_OPTION,DialogDescriptor.DEFAULT_ALIGN, null, null, false);
```

Option 2) Do some black magic with java reflection to access and change the value of the default selected button, or replace the private field, with your custom implementation that overrides the default behavior.

example code:

```
OptionsDisplayer displayer = OptionsDisplayer.getDefault();        
    Object impl = getField(displayer, "impl"); 
    if(impl != null){
        WeakReference<DialogDescriptor> descriptorRef = (WeakReference<DialogDescriptor>)getField(impl, "descriptorRef");
        if(descriptorRef != null){                
            DialogDescriptor descriptor = descriptorRef.get();
            //change default initial selected butten from "OK" to "CANCEL"
            descriptor.setValue(DialogDescriptor.CANCEL_OPTION); //change default initial selected butten from "OK" to "CANCEL"
        }
    }

/**
 * Java reflection utility method to get the Object for a given field regardless of whether it is private or not, by it's given field name.
 * @param obj The Object that contains the desired field.
 * @param fieldName The name of the field
 * @return The Object with the given fieldName found in Object 'obj'. Returns null if no such field exists.
 */
public static Object getField(Object obj, String fieldName) {
    Class tmpClass = obj.getClass();
    do {
        try {
            Field f = tmpClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            if(f != null){
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return f.get(obj);
            }                
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            tmpClass = tmpClass.getSuperclass();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } while (tmpClass != null);
    return null; //null if not found
}
```

Option 3) More java black-magic, intercept the bytecode loading at the classloader, and change it before it is loaded in the JVM. e.g. use bytecode manipulation librairies such as AspectJ, Javassist, ASM or CGLib

Comment: I tried Option:2 and with little changes from your example code , i was able to shift focus..